# IndexError: list index out of range while using bs4

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, beautifulsoup

This I the Link where I am trying to fetch data  [flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com/kanika-women-s-nighty/p/itmed2yqzdgqgz3q?pid=NDNED2YQU9HPESEA&al=FvCq1Xh5FyMN11cjuYgL6MldugMWZuE7svdkPtTGUY6%2F3Fk9x0T1uX3Tym%2F%2F6pAalZzKUG0RUT0%3D&ref=L%3A9146140901050108837&srno=p_14&query=nighty&otracker=from-search)

and the part of code :

```
   <div class="toolbar-wrap line section">
   <div class="ratings-reviews-wrap">
      <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" class="ratings-reviews line omniture-field">
         <div class="ratings">
            <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="1">
            <div class="fk-stars" title="1 stars">
               <span class="unfilled">★★★★★</span>
               <span class="rating filled" style="width:20%">
               ★★★★★
               </span>
            </div>
            <div class="count">
               <span itemprop="ratingCount">2</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

here I have to fetch 1 star from `title= 1 star` and 2 from `<span itemprop="ratingCount">2</span>`

I try the following code

```
 x = link_soup.find_all("div",class_='fk-stars')[0].get('title')

 print x, " product_star"
 y = link_soup.find_all("span",itemprop="ratingCount")[0].string.strip()
 print y
```

but It give the

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Comment: this is the link where I am try to soup  http://www.flipkart.com/kanika-women-s-nighty/p/itmed2yqzdgqgz3q?pid=NDNED2YQU9HPESEA&al=FvCq1Xh5FyMN11cjuYgL6MldugMWZuE7svdkPtTGUY6%2F3Fk9x0T1uX3Tym%2F%2F6pAalZzKUG0RUT0%3D&ref=L%3A9146140901050108837&srno=p_14&query=nighty&otracker=from-search

Comment: Works fine for me too. Are there any collections involved? Maybe you are iterating through a list of divs?

Comment: Neither of those tags exist in the HTML of http://www.flipkart.com/kanika-women-s-nighty/p/itmed2yqzdgqgz3q?pid=NDNED2YQU9HPESEA&al=FvCq1Xh5FyMN11cjuYgL6MldugMWZuE7svdkPtTGUY6%2F3Fk9x0T1uX3Tym%2F%2F6pAalZzKUG0RUT0%3D&ref=L%3A9146140901050108837&srno=p_14&query=nighty&otracker=from-search

Comment: @mhawke I copy from there.  open that link and right click on product rating star -> Inspect Element  then You will get

Comment: @YAM: the content is not there if you download the URL with Python `requests`, `urllib`, etc. You see it in your browser because that content is dynamically downloaded and inserted into the page. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The content that you see in the browser is not actually present in the raw HTML that is retrieved from [this URL](http://www.flipkart.com/kanika-women-s-nighty/p/itmed2yqzdgqgz3q?pid=NDNED2YQU9HPESEA&al=FvCq1Xh5FyMN11cjuYgL6MldugMWZuE7svdkPtTGUY6%2F3Fk9x0T1uX3Tym%2F%2F6pAalZzKUG0RUT0%3D&ref=L%3A9146140901050108837&srno=p_14&query=nighty&otracker=from-search).

When loaded with a browser, the page executes AJAX calls to load additional content, which is then dynamically inserted into the page. One of the calls gets the ratings info that you are after. Specifically [this URL](http://www.flipkart.com/lc/p/pv1/spotList1/spot1/actionBar?pid=NDNED2YQU9HPESEA&abData=6d9ab6f0693f6dc15154541cfd54a56b&abbuckets=BAABBBBAdABB&loadDeferred=true&__FK=V2661483a2e2f79dac68f2acd978b3e1ees2e34Bz8%2FUyJ1Qj8%2Fdz8wQD8%2FP4mQXkkOEy4GrLiCq0Th7nnNeHQfAPNz4auu1BnL6vymheiEFxy6mR50cfLIuBl5nWlNODYDqOQkiAoG8Xhejvy3GJmwnR4IDLTVwHV32gKtpz%2F6rlb6MBpjxOXzqwgnLQjGzL%2BwYaSAKrYgRgElQpkjFRftPUWMxysAKjngkTV6UrzB128nCOqIdU3kTgNYmpri3xOmKfFKzb5kKv5zC8mqLlLatQ2VTM91Xb7wnLsGTKxhXn9vZnyJyU%2BMbEYivNMsKR4%2FeGZY65KjPl1RHqOLOyye0p8PIn2ZuGh0bfWmpPML9kob6%2BLz5duHYLVraPLdG8UjYW%2FyA9y6ldWkKSp37%2FrhWchAodHmrBsRRvOtcCPvGy7D%2BAbzqMcICMUBUIYOLdYmKWWuXj7BylbQZuE%3D) is the one that contains the HTML that is inserted as the "action bar".

But if you retrieve the main page using Python, e.g. with `requests`, `urllib` et. al., the dynamic content is not loaded and that is why BeautifulSoup can't find the tags.

You could analyse the main page to find the actual link, retrieve that, and then run it through BeautifulSoup. The link looks like it begins with `/p/pv1/spotList1/spot1/actionBar` so that, or perhaps `actionBar` is sufficient to locate the actual link.

Or you could use `selenium` to load the page and then grab and process the rendered HTML.